# How can I search for all contacts without email?

Tags: search

To find offline members or incomplete records, I would like to list all contacts that do not have an email address set. Is there a way to search for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Search - Search Builder.

Choose:

- Contacts
- Email
- Primary
- Is Empty

Then on the results screen you can also from the Actions dropdown choose Groups - Create Smart Group to save this search so you can run it again in the future and because it's a Smart Group it will automatically adjust the results to be current.

Comment: will "Primary" empty also catch contacts that may have only an email set for "Private" or "Work"?

Comment: Yes. If they have at least one email then one will have to be primary. You can't have an email without one being primary. (If you can then that's a bug.)